# how wordpress a post add comment only for logged users?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, comments, hook

How a post in wordpress add comment only for logged users?

visitors must answer their own add in comments. but i need a post, leave a comment (only for logged users) and users must register to site beforce add comment to post

can use functions file to do it ?

i found that 2 code but not work and do not know how to use it:

in facing link find this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user

Code:

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

and in facing link find this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form

code:

```
'<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>'
```

and from the combination of these two together, I built below function!

```
<?php
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
    // Not logged in.
    '<p class="must-log-in">' .  sprintf( __( 'You must be <a href="%s">logged in</a> to post a comment.' ), wp_login_url( apply_filters( 'the_permalink', get_permalink( ) ) ) ) . '</p>'
} else {
    // Logged in.
}
?>
```

and add this to my post with [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/) plugin for use only (a) post

please help me to do this. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Discussion you will find the option: `Users must be registered and logged in to comment`. - http://prntscr.com/k2f02d

Checked this option and save the settings your requirement will be fulfilled.

Comment: thank you very much. but need only for one (a) post. post id. not all posts and pages commets.

Answer (score 0):

Review below menu navigation

```
Settings >>> Discussion 
Checked the "Users must be registered and logged in to comment " checkbox
```

Comment: thank you very much. but need only for one (a) post. post id. not all posts and pages commets.